# Cross scripting attack by appending link url in our web site

Tags: .net

Our site is facing problem of cross scripting attack in the form of
appending link url in our site pages
Previous attack was on near by 1 month month ago,
on that we have done following changes to our site :
1. parametrized queries
2. Use of Html Encode
3. RequestValidation="True" in web.config
and we successfully stop that attack by using above methods

Now After one month later we again get affected with same xss attack

if anyone have any suggestions about what we can do more to stop it?

Answer (score 3):

xss is most often caused by allowing raw content (such as user-entered html, containing `<script>` blocks) to be rendered directly (not escaped or sanitized) to the client. Simply: *don't allow that*. Find whatever is either:

- rendering the content without escaping it, or
- allowing in input *intended* to be displayed as-is (html, etc) without sanitizing it

and *fix that*. In the case of ASP.NET aspx, make sure you use `<%:` rather than `<%=` (unless you *know* the content is clean and intended to be written raw) - as that does an html-encode if appropriate. In cshtml (razor), `@` does an encode by default anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider using Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library, its way better for encoding html markup than standard .NET

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28589
```